# Reusing ListFragment with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I have a 7 tabs and their shared fragment whose data depends on XML received from url. The problem is if I set setOffscreenPageLimit(6) and for first tab, everything is fine for tab number 1 but tab number 2 to 7 shows the data from url that supposed to show in last tab.

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this, negeri);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
    actionBar.setTitle("List");
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        


    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));

    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
```

FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

static Context context;
static Resources res = null;
static String[] CONTENT = null;



public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context c, String negeri) {
    super(fm);

    context = c;

    res = context.getResources();



        CONTENT = res.getStringArray(R.array.values);






}


@Override
public ListFragment getItem(int index) {


    return DaerahFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[index]);



}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return CONTENT.length;
}

public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
       return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

}

ListFragment;

```
public static ListFragment newInstance(String daerahVal) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_DAERAH, daerahVal);
    DaerahFragment fragment = new DaerahFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       // Bundle args = getArguments();
        //String daerah=args.getString("daerah");

        daerah = getArguments().getString(ARG_DAERAH);

         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "daerah= " + daerah , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




        URL  = "http://www.url.com/android/daerahMarker.php?daerah="+daerah;


        setRetainInstance(true);


        if (mListViewScrollPos != null && adapter != null) {
            getListView().onRestoreInstanceState(mListViewScrollPos);
        } else {

        myTask = new TalkToServer();
        myTask.execute();

        }


      }
```

TQ

Comment: tab number 2 to 7 shows the data from url that supposed to show in last tab.

Comment: you dont need to send the argument and create static instance of the fragment, the fragment is like any pojo ( model ) class you could pass any setter to it, for example in your adapter onItem you could do MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment(); 
fragment.setUrl(MyUrl.get(position)); return fragement.

Comment: so, i need to setup a new class?

Answer (score 0):

i solved this

just remove static

```
static String URL = "";
```

to

```
String URL = "";
```

:)